# how to store values in a 1D array into a 2D array in Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Hi I would like to store values of a 1D array into a 2D array.
My 1D array has 50 elements and I want to store it in a 5x10 array, but whenever I do that, it always gives me a "Index out of range" error
Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
var info2d = [[String]]()
var dataArray = outputdata.components(separatedBy: ";")
for j in 0...10 {
    for i in 0...5 {
        info2d[i][j] = dataArray[(j)*5+i]
        print(info2d[i][j])

    }
}
```

Comment: post your tried code?

Comment: Add the code to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of error in your code.

`info2d` must be initialised with default values before using it by index

```
// initialising 2d array with empty string value
var info2d = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", count: 10), count: 5)
```

Secondly `for` loop with `...` includes the last value too, use `..<`

```
for j in 0..<10 {
    //...
}
```

Thirdly `(j)*5+i` is incorrect too.

Better Read how to use arrays, collections and for loop in swift.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience im new to swift and iOS programming.
I fixed the errors you mentioned above and it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of ArraySlice for this.

```
var arr2D = [[String]]()

for i in 0..<5 {
    let start = i * 10
    let end = start + 10
    let slice = dataArray[start..<end] //Create an ArraySlice
    arr2D.append(Array(slice)) //Create new Array from ArraySlice
}
```